# How to update Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I used an early version of Bootstrap. Is there any way I can update all Twitter Bootstrap files at once?

Comment: Update the standalone bootstrap files? Ruby gem?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to visit [Bootstrap's upgrading page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/upgrading.html) and see which changes affect your implementation.

After replacing your actual bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js files with the new ones, many changes to your code will be simple Find & Replace fixes. The upgrading page breaks down what you need to change for upgrading, and it has it broken down by section so you can only use the parts relevant to you.

Comment: UPDATE: The Bootstrap upgrade page has been pulled as they are moving closer to releasing 3.0. At this point, so much has changed that you probably don't have an easy road ahead regardless of how you upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I create a 'project.less' file in the same directory as 'bootstrap.less'. 'project.less' includes 'bootstrap.less' on the first line. Then I override add or override styles as needed. I also modify the variables.less file, but with clear comments on which items I modified. When I am ready to generate my CSS, I run lessc on my project.less file. Doing this made it much much easier for me to upgrade to 2.1.1. -- I just replaced all of the bootstrap less files, added the styles I'd modified in 'variables.less' then re-ran lessc.

Answer (score 1):

My best advice would be to review the Bootstrap page and see what things have changed. Download the new files and create a fork of your project (if you are using Git) and substitute the new Bootstrap files in place of the old ones. See what breaks and try to work from there. I know it sounds tedious but it might not be terrible depending on how much of Bootstrap you used in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but the issue you will face it that the class names have changed quite a bit... so just updating the files will not be the biggest pain.